# PHP Modify Variable

Tags: php

There is a PHP file called test2.php,the code is in follow:

```
<?php
$data=array(
    'name' => 'jack',
    'age' => 8,
);
?>
```

I want to modify the $data in anoher php file called test1.php,
but i find that if only use:

```
require_once "./test2.php";
$data['age']=10;
echo $data['age'];
```

Although the output is 10,but $data in test2.php dosen't change.

I want to know how to edit a PHP file in anoher PHP file.

Comment: "_but $data in test1.php dosen't change_" You mean `test2.php`? Why would that change, you'd need to edit/save/write new contents to the file.

Comment: I think you need to use SESSION https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: You seem to be confused with the basics.

Comment: Using a SESSION won't alter/change the file

Comment: This looks more like you need to store the values in a database or in some form of .env file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the contents of test2.php, you need to use a code editor (or... thru file_put_contents (make sure your file is writable), or use a database approach to store the data values, etc.)

However, if you `just` want to change the value of the age element of the $data array thru programming, then you can use session variables to do what you want

So change **test2.php** to

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["data"])) {
   $_SESSION["data"]=array(
            'name' => 'jack',
            'age' => 8,
   );
}

echo $_SESSION["data"]["age"];


?>
```

and use the following as **test1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

//require_once "./test2.php";
//$data['age']=10;
//echo $data['age'];

$_SESSION["data"]["age"]=10;

echo "Data changed, please visit test2.php to see the effect";

?>
```

Please try these steps:

1. visit the test2.php and see the value of  $_SESSION["data"]["age"] echoed
2. visit the test1.php (to change the data)
3. visit test2.php and see what happens

Comment: "_To change the contents of test2.php, you need to use a code editor._" So `file_put_contents` wouldn't work?

Comment: Oh of course file_put_contents will also work, let me slightly change my answer :)